# PHP か JavaScript で、画像内の一番多い範囲で使用されているカラーコードを取得するライブラリはありますか？

Tags: javascript, php, 画像

PHP か JavaScript で、画像内の一番多い範囲で使用されているカラーコード(一つだけ)を取得したいです。参考になりそうなページや、ライブラリはありますか？

※画像クリックした地点の色を取得したいわけではありません

Answer (score 0):

英語版で [類似の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10290259) があり、その中の一つとしてPHP向けの [ColorExtractor (GitHub)](https://github.com/thephpleague/color-extractor) が紹介されています。

[Detect main colors in an image with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10290259)

**Epoc さんの回答:**

```php
use League\ColorExtractor\Palette;

$palette = Palette::fromFilename('some/image.png');

$topEightColors = $palette->getMostUsedColors(8);
```